# Client Failed to access class (xxxxx): Can't locate xxxxx.pm in @INC - PERL

Tags: perl, soap

I am trying to run a Perl SOAP server, it starts up alright, but when a method is called remotely I get the following message:

> SOAP::Serializer::envelope: Client Failed to access class (HELLO):
>   Can't locate HELLO.pm in @INC (@INC contains:) at (eval 127) line 3.

Now I assume this is because @INC does not specify where my HELLO.pm file resides? Although where abouts can I define this? I have tried adding the following to my script and placing the class (Hello.pm) there but no luck:

```
BEGIN {
  push(@INC, '/etc/perl/');
};
```

My code is as follows (soapserver.pl):

```
BEGIN {
  push(@INC, '/etc/perl/');
};
#- SoapHttpServerTrace.pl
#- Copyright (c) 2002 by Dr. Herong Yang
   use SOAP::Lite +trace;
   use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;
   my $daemon = SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Daemon
      -> new (LocalAddr => 'XX.XX.XX.XX', LocalPort => 8001, listen => 5);
   $daemon -> dispatch_to('Hello::hello');
   print "Contact SOAP server at ", $daemon->url, "\n";
   $daemon->handle();
```

Comment: Did you edit the error message? I don't see how SOAP could have been loaded if @INC is empty. What is the error message with your new code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said your file is named Hello.pm, but the error message indicates an attempt to load HELLO.pm. Fix whichever of these is wrong.